# jQuery code working in Safari, but half in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, safari, incompatibility

I've got the following piece of code:

```
vote = $('input.vote', $($("ul#statement_forms li.statement")[current])).attr("value");
alert(vote);
```

Where the variable current is an integer. If i run this in Safari it works as expected (it alerts the value of vote), but not in IE, though, when i run this:

```
alert($('input.vote', $($("ul#statement_forms li.statement")[current])).attr("value"));
```

IE Also alerts the value, so i guess the problem is that it wont assign the value to the variable.

I tried using jQuery 1.5.1, 1.3.1 and 1.2.6 but no difference.

I'm hoping one of you guys can help me out..

Thanks!

Comment: Whats happens in ie when you do it the first way? it is perfectly valid code which should work just fine.

Comment: Is "vote" a global variable?  Is there an element on your page whose "id" is "vote"?

Comment: The first way IE just quits running JS, it says "Object doesnt support this property or method" (?!)

Comment: Vote isnt a global variable, it's defined at this posted line, and yes there is a div id called vote. Why should that be a problem?

Comment: Actually it looks a whole lot like a global variable, given that you didn't declare it with `var`.  And it could be a problem because we're talking about IE here ... try calling it "voote" instead of "vote" and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

> Vote isnt a global variable, it's defined at this posted line

You're missing `var` before `vote` to actually declare the variable at this point.  Safari apparently doesn't care, but IE doesn't like it.

On a side note: jQuery has `.val()` and `.val("something")` functions to retrieve and set the value of `input` and `select` elements.